# Android 11 get birthday of contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to query birthday of all the contacts. This is what I am using --

```
    private val PROJECTION: Array<out String> = arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
    )

    private val SELECTION: String =
        "${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} = ? AND ${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE} = ${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY}"

    // Defines a variable for the search string
    private val searchString: String = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE

    // Defines the array to hold values that replace the ?
    private val selectionArgs = arrayOf(searchString)
```

```
    override fun onCreateLoader(loaderId: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
        // Starts the query
        return activity?.let {
            return CursorLoader(
                it,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION,
                SELECTION,
                selectionArgs,
                null
            )
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException()
    }
```

I am getting

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: mimetype (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, lookup, display_name FROM view_contacts WHERE ((1)) AND (mimetype = ? AND data2 = 3)
```

Has `mimetype` field been removed from Android 11? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table at `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` only contains very generic contact info, like _ID, DISPLAY_NAME, etc.
It doesn't contain the actual data of a contact, such as phones, emails, events, etc.

Those are stored in a separate table `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`, so you'll need to change the table in your cursorLoader to that.

Also, your projection would need to change to:

```
private val PROJECTION: Array<out String> = arrayOf(
    Data.CONTACT_ID,
    Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
)
```